# How could Britannica's explanation of Venn diagrams work?

Tags: logic

[image]Britannica.com/biography/John-Venn says the rings on the left are a Venn diagram of the syllogism “Some mammals are carnivores; all mammals are animals; therefore, some animals are carnivores” but ignoring the mysterious “X”, that doesn’t seem quite so.

“Some mammals *are* carnivores” but isn’t the second premise of the diagram not “all…” but rather “some mammals are animals”?

Shouldn’t “all mammals are animals” be shown as set M fully enclosed by set A, as in the rings on the right?

Doesn’t the difference matter quite a lot?

Comment: The shaded areas in the left type of diagram are supposed to be excluded areas, i.e. there can be no objects in those areas, so that diagram does show the only objects in the non-shaded part of the 'mammals' circle must be in the 'animals' circle. Sometimes the reverse convention is used and the shaded areas are allowed objects while the white areas are excluded, see [here](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/shading-venn-diagrams.html).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Thanks and I don't see the shading as relevant, nor how that diagram does show the only objects in the non-shaded part of the 'mammals' circle must be in the 'animals' circle could matter.

How am I mistaken in thinking “all mammals are animals” requires the set of mammals to be not merely intersecting, but wholly enclosed by the set of animals?

Comment: Well, that's what the shading means in that type of diagram--those areas are excluded, the set "mammals" only consists of the non-shaded areas in that diagram. So, the set "mammals" *is* wholly contained within the set "animals", the way the sets are defined in that diagram.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Then if we drop the set C and the mysterious X, the remaining shaded M and unshaded A express not an intersection but a total inclusion… or did I miss something?

Comment: The X is not shaded, it's not meant to be dropped. I think the X area represents "some mammals are carnivores", and since that area is also part of "animals", it shows that "some mammals are animals" must be true. And why do you mention dropping the set C? Only the shaded areas are supposed to be dropped, most of C is non-shaded.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that it shows "some animals are carnivores" must be true, though in Aristotelian logic it is also true that "all mammals are animals" implies "some mammals are animals" (BTW, this implication doesn't actually work in modern first-order logic because it defines its equivalent of 'all mammals are animals' to be true even in the case where there are no mammals).

Comment: Some logical treatments involve the statement "there are no mammals which are not animals". The Britannica version can be useful in illustrating such an argument.

Comment: You are confused by the diagrams because you likely believed BOTH diagrams are Venn diagrams which is false. The two diagrams are NOT Venn diagrams.  Philosophy uses Venn diagrams while Math uses Euler diagrams.  The Venn diagram is on the LEFT. THE Euler diagram is on the right. The Venn diagram displays all possible variations. The Euler does not show all possible variations but all  variations you are aware of. How would you which circle goes into another? You would need prior knowledge of the topic just to analyze it. You are limited with Euler diagrams. Venn diagrams aren't limited.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's very helpful

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Venn diagrams and Euler diagrams look similar and are sometimes confused. A Venn diagram always shows shows areas of intersections of sets, even if those areas cannot have members. It then marks possible/impossible areas with color.

In the Venn diagram, the circle labelled M for Mammals is show to be a subset of the circle A for animals, because all areas of M outside A are marked with color to be impossible/empty. All possible areas of M are also in A, so anything in M is also in A, so M is a subset of A in the diagram.

With Venn diagrams, the user first has to draw the standard circles, and then think about which area can be empty. With Euler diagrams, a user first thinks of relationships, and then draws shaped to illustrate their thinking.

The X stand for the area marking the conclusion "therefore done animals are carnivores".

The diagram on the right is an Euler diagram.

Both diagrams could be right and existing the same, different tools to show the same situation.

Comment: If you mean that the two diagrams describe different scenarios, fine.

If they're supposed to represent the same situation - which is why I Posted the Question - they can't both be correct. That one insists and the other denies M is a sub-set of A makes them not merely different, but wholly incompatible.

I've learned here that Venn and Euler diagrams look similar and are sometimes confused. Still how, in itself could 'Venn always shows shows… intersections… even if they cannot have members. It then marks possible/impossible areas with color…' matter here?

More…

Comment: Further… quite apart from any question or argument, I felt somehow privileged to be told, in about 1963, that my year was the first to be taught 'new maths'.

OMG! Can anyone imagine how it felt for an eight-year-old to be told be trusted and admired teacher that he and his like were the first to be granted new knowledge?

We were specifically told that 'new maths' had come about through changes in the understanding of that which was known; 'new maths' would enable many advances in any number of techniques and technologies and 'new maths' would be needed to understand any of that.

More…

Comment: Further… Despite having spent years in IT training and support, I don't recall one instance of anything I was taught at school about 'new maths' coming into play.

In casual reading, of course but that's no part of the bright new world my teachers promised, in clear good faith.

Even aged eight, it seemed obvious that if the people who designed new-fangled gadgets had got by on traditional maths, no-one else was going to need much more.

If that looks like a rant, I hoped to point out that our education system has too long focussed on the wrong details at the wrong level.

Comment: I've added more details to my response regarding your question. I will not respond to your off topic comments and i recommend deleting them, following the rules of this site.

Answer (score 0):

The difference matters. Venn diagrams are intended for the representation of all *logically possible* relations, not merely *actual* ones. A subtle, but logically significant difference: The syllogism states that all mammals are animals, not that mammals constitute a subset of animals.

Comment: There I thought I was starting to get it, and now how is there a difference between "all mammals are animals" and "mammals constitute a subset of animals."

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin Spend some time on this issue: According to the usual conception of formal languages, '(for) all' is a logical quantifier, whereas 'element of' (hence, 'subset of') is a non-logical (set-theoretical) predicate. Don't be dispirited, even many professional philosophers miss such distinctions.

Comment: Thanks and where did '(for) all' or 'element of' come into this?

Comment: What you meant might well be true.

Why not define both the official set of formal languages and the authority for that?

Do you insist not one language in which '(for) all' is a logical quantifier, whereas 'element of' (hence, 'subset of') is a non-logical (set-theoretical) predicate could be ‘formal’?

Could you consider the possibility that some of the professional philosophers you mentioned in fact missed nothing but rather, such distinctions mattered to them on the same scale as pin dancing?

Could most readers share their view, and your group be the ones missing?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin rigour in philosophy is not a given, it is something that must be striven for. We have to sharpen our notions, delimit our concepts, and make our ideas clear and distinct. You may wish to discuss your thoughts further by follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks and I was seeking clarity, not argument. Can you go for clarity?